# Do I need a subselect?

Tags: mysql, sql

My two tables are:

```
 table User ( userid,  username,  ... )
 table Bookings ( bookingid, userid, destination, ...)
```

I want to list all Bookings by those users who have a booking where destination = "Greece";

```
first match: (user name) 
  Destination: Greece ( = match criteria) 
  Destination: [other destinations from this user]
  Destination: destionation n ...

second match: (user name) 
  Destination: Greece 
  Destionation: [other destionations]

[...]
```

I am new to more complex SQL. I think you need a subselect for this. But how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it with a JOIN:

The logic is that in the subquery you retrieve the userid's for users that have a matching booking.

The you use that list of id's to join again with the bookings table. So, this will get you a list of all the users that match your first criterion.

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM Bookings b
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT userid
    FROM Bookings
    WHERE destination = "Greece"
    GROUP BY userid
) aux ON aux.userid = b.userid
```

PS:

As @Kickstart points out in a comment, you need to add a `SELECT DISTINCT userid` or a `GROUP BY userid` in the subquery. Otherwise you will most likely get repeated rows.

Comment: Note that this will bring back duplicate rows for any users who have 2 bookings for the destination of Greece. You could use SELECT DISTINCT in the subquery to get around this

Comment: @Kickstart. Good catch. I'd generally go with a GROUP BY userid. Not for any particular reason, just because that's how I'm used to doing it; anyway, I don't know if SELECT DISTINCT would be faster or slower (or perhaps it makes no diffence performance-wise).

Comment: I too tend to prefer using GROUP BY as most of the time when doing something similar I do need some aggregated value from the sub select (or might well with future developments of the code).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to do this is to put the logic in the `where` clause:

```
select b.*
from bookings b
where b.userid in (select b2.userid from bookings b2 where b2.destination = 'Greece')
order by b.userid;
```

In earlier versions of MySQL, this will be more efficient using `exists`:

```
select b.*
from bookings b
where exists (select 1 from bookings b2 where b2.userid = b.userid and b2.destination = 'Greece')
order by b.userid;
```

If you want the information summarized by user, you can put the list of destinations in a single field this way:

```
select u.*, group_concat(b.destination) as destinations
from users u join
     bookings b
     on u.userid = b.userid
group by u.userid
having sum(b.destination = 'Greece') > 0;
```

Comment: I have found MySQL subselect performance to be appalling. Prefer joins where possible.

Comment: @cja . . . You have to be very careful when making such general statements.  Sometimes subqueries work fine (performance-wise).  Sometimes they don't.

Comment: cja, could you please provide an example for my use case. That would be great. thanks.

Comment: @usario Sadly my current job forces me to use SQL Server. It's been a year since I used MySQL so I don't remember exact queries. Every subquery I ever wrote in MySQL was many times slower than a corresponding join or than doing multiple simpler selects and then processing the data in memory

Comment: MySQL often suffers for any large correlated subqueries. Joining against a subquery will often be FAR faster unless that subquery brings back a large number of rows of which only a tiny number are required.